# Trying Error Handling

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-ise

I am trying to run a script where if there is an error I wan't to write something and if there was no error write to host that everything worked.

Here is part of the script where I'm struggling with.

```
try { 
    New-VM -VMName "$Name"  -NewVHDPath "E:\Microsoft Hyper V\$Name\$Name.vhdx" -NewVHDSizeBytes $VHDSizeBytes -Generation $Generation  -SwitchName "$Switchname" -Path $VMPath | Out-Null
    Set-VMMemory -VMName "$Name" -DynamicMemoryEnabled $true -StartupBytes $MaxStartBytes
    switch (Read-Host "Type (Win10) For Windows 10 Iso file OR (Svr16) For Windows Server 2016"){
        'Win10' {Add-VMDvdDrive -VMName "$Name" -Path E:\ISO\Windows.iso }
        'Svr16' {Add-VMDvdDrive -VMName "$Name" -Path E:\ISO\14393.0.160715-1616.RS1_RELEASE_SERVER_EVAL_X64FRE_EN-US.ISO}
        default {Write-Host "No Such ISO" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red }
    }
    Write-Output (Write-Host "VM '$Name' Created Successfuly" -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Green )
}
Catch {
    Write-Output (Write-Host " Creation Of Virtual Machine '$Name' Failed!"  -BackgroundColor Black -ForegroundColor Red | Write-Error )
}
```

What I need is to try everything between the **{ }** and write **"The VM Created successfully"** , And if the VM Was not created successfully then write to host **"The Creation Failed"**.

I am hoping someone can understand what I'm trying to accomplish here.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: To trigger the catch block you need to have a terminating error. If the cmdlets you use do not trigger terminating errors by themselfs you need to set the `-ErrorAction Stop` inside the try block.

Comment: I understood what you mean, but do i need to add  " -ErrorAction Stop " after each command inside the " Try " Block ?

Comment: You could set it for each command you want to trigger terminating errors. But it should also work if you set the `$ErrorActionPreference` variable to `[System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Stop`

Comment: Hmmmm ... That's actually a philosophical question. ;-)  If you need to know  excatly which one of your commands failed you would need a try - catch - block for each command. But @J.Bergmann's recommendation would work as well.

Comment: Personally I just have one try then multiple catches for specific errors and one default catch for anything I didn't think of.

Comment: I will try to make something work out of this, I understand how Try catch works better now thanks to you.